# Find out kill session in php using java script

Tags: php-5.5

I have started a session on my `login.php` page. I have used `javascript.js` file to send a request to the `login.php` page and get some data as response. I want to check on that js file if the session has been killed or has expired or is still started. If it is still started, then I would like to print or alert session array or name. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The session is a server side thing, you cannot access it using jQuery. The only way to do this is to write the value into a script block on the page as a Javascript variable, and reference it that way, or to make an AJAX request to a page that then returns the logged in status. There's no way for your client to directly access the session state in any server language.

Comment: javasript.js is another file when login html call to js file then it check on login.php and then response check on js.

Comment: that's how it works. What's the problem now, is it got errors? Show your code, or errors.

Comment: see when I alert my data its alert on js is ok. but when header location change on home.php it goes retive that page and again come back to login. uninitialize session destroy.

Comment: there is no code in your question. we can not seen anything!

Comment: yes. the big code is there..Sorry but I can't paste.so i just want idea about how to check if session start on one page and redirect on other page. if session_start() start once socan we maintain all pages on that session page only.